# How to deal with nbsp in html elements in Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**I am using space between & and nbsp below although in my code there is no space.**

I am trying web scraping with Beautifulsoup and currently stuck on an issue. I was able to successfully get the elements that I would require with find_all, its in a table so first is the key and second is the value. So I use the key variable name set in the website to matchcase with my required key with if statement and then obtain the related value for it, but some key variables in the html contain ***& nbsp;*** in between the text of key variable name. The If statement doesn't match for the variables where ever ***& nbsp;*** is present.

below is html from Google Chrome inspect mode

```
<tr valign="top">
        <td><b>Active&nbsp;since:</b></td>
        <td><a href="/InterH1/Category:E_2012" title="Category:2021 H1">14199083</a> (212E)</td>
    </tr>
```

below code is from the soup method

```
<tr valign="top">
<td><b>Active since:</b></td>
<td><a href="/InterH1/Category:E_2012" title="Category:2021 H1">14199083</a> (212E)</td>
</tr>
```

The If statement works for all variables where ever the key variable is a single word with no spaces as seen below

```
if keycheck[0].get_text().strip() == "Year:":
        intercincom_eight_year = keycheck[1].get_text().strip()
```

but it fails whereever the key variable contains ***& nbsp;*** in it such as

```
if keycheck[0].get_text().strip().replace("&nbsp;", " ") == "Active since:":
        intercincom_eight_active = keycheck[1].get_text().strip()
```

or

```
if keycheck[0].get_text().strip() == "Active since:":
        intercincom_eight_active = keycheck[1].get_text().strip()
```

I dont think I have to use replace to remove nbsp with a blank space because whenever I am printing the key variable it prints without nbsp unlike it is present in the chrome inspect mode. for eg

```
        print(keycheck[0].get_text().strip())
```

gives ***Active year:*** instead of ***Active& nbsp;since:*** but it still doesnt matchcase in the if statement

```
if keycheck[0].get_text().strip() == "Active since:":
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that you'll need to use the Unicode representation for a non-breaking space, which is `u'\xa0'`. Seeing as the string literal from Beautiful Soup doesn't explicitly contain "`&nbsp;`," your call to `replace()` could be searching for a string that isn't there.

```py
>>> print(u'\xa0' == " ")
False

>>> print(u'\xa0' == "&nbsp;") 
False
```

For further clarification in regards to your code, you should be able to implement this by changing "`&nbsp;`" in your call to `replace()` to `"\xa0"`, therefore...

```py
keycheck[0].get_text().strip().replace("\xa0", " ") == "Active since:":
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am a beginner in python so still confused as per your post, could you please elaborate on how to proceed with if possible. i did check unicode representation that are mentioned in other answers but they were all mostly dealing with files, I am not sure how to include it here with soup, your time and help is appreciated.

Comment: You would simply change the first argument in your `replace()` to `\xa0`, so... `keycheck[0].get_text().strip().replace("\xa0", " ") == "Active since:":`

Comment: If I were to offer any additional advice, you can save yourself some trouble by running `.lower()` on the string you're checking as well, that way you won't have to worry about uppercase or lowercase in your comparisons.